# Extract only dates part excluding time from Mysql two tables and compare them in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables in Database and both fields has the datetime columns
I want to extract only the date part form the columns and compare it.
MySql give the YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format and I can't compare because of the time difference even though the date is same.

```
SELECT * FROM  table1;
SELECT * FROM  table2;

table1.date == table2.date
```

How can I only compare date excluding time in PHP?

Comment: Have you tried the explode function call with whitespace as delimeter and use the first argument of the result? http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: why don't you use single query for that like `SELECT * FROM table1,table2 WHERE date(table1.date) = date(table2.date)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get date+time($table1_date) from Mysql and exclude time in PHP like this:

```
$full_date = strtotime($table1_date);
$date_only = date("d-m-Y", $full_date);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use MySQL's [DATE_FORMAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function to format the date, e.g.:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m-%d') FROM table;
```

Once you get the dates from both the tables, you can show/compare them in php.